# How to get the requested file name in BaseHTTPServer in python?

Tags: python, http, python-2.7, network-programming

I'm writing an HTTP server in Python and I need to get the name of the requested file from the sent request in order to send from from the server

```
Here is my code:
from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler,HTTPServer
import os.path
from os import curdir, sep

PortNum = 8080


class myHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

#Handler for the GET requests
def do_GET(self):
    if self.path=="/":
        print os.path.splitext(self.path)[0]
        print self.path
        print "my code"
        self.path="/index_example3.html"

    try:
        #Check the file extension required and
        #set the right mime type


        extension = os.path.splitext(self.path)[-1]
        mime_types = {
       '.html': 'text/html',
       '.jpg':'image/jpg',
        '.gif': 'image/gif',
       '.js': 'application/javascript',
       '.css': 'text/css',
        }

        mimetype = mime_types.get(extension)
        sendReply = mimetype is not None

        if sendReply == True:
            #open the static file requested and send it
            f=open(curdir+sep+self.path)
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Content-type',mimetype)
            self.wfile.write(f.read())
            f.close()
        return
    except IOError:
        self.send_error(404,'File Not Found'% self.path)




try:
   #Create a web server and define thehandler to manage the
   #incoming request
   server = HTTPServer(('',PortNum),myHandler)
   print('Started httpserver on port ',PortNum)
   #wait forever for incoming http requests
   server.serve_forever()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print '^C received, shuting down the web server'
    server.socket.close()
```

I have used the self.path to get the whole path but it only contains a '/' character and the when the request is a "POST" request it contains '/send' in the documentation page of this library [HERE](https://docs.python.org/2/library/basehttpserver.html) I couldn't fine any thing useful

I want to get the file name requested I don't know what self.path contains really.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I run your codes, it looks work well.

When I entered localhost:8080/test.html, server printed

> 127.0.0.1 - - [28/Nov/2014 16:55:36] "GET /**test.html** HTTP/1.1" 200 -

Isn't it what you want to get?

Comment: This rather sould be in a comment and not an answer

Comment: yes you are right it works fine but how about the POST requests why it contains '/send'?

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation of the Python BaseHTTPserver library :

path
    Contains the request path.

so that if a client send sth like `127.1.1.1:8080`
the self.path only contains a `'/'` character but if it is sth like `127.1.1.1:8080/index.html`

the `self.path` contains `'index.html'` and there is no problem

but I don't know why in a POST request there exists a `'/send'` in the self.path