# How to get incomng file type from Simple HTTP server python (BaseHTTPRequestHandler)

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, curl

```
class SimpleHTTPRequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_POST(self):
        # I can get the file binary data from here 
        data = self.rfile.read(int(self.headers['Content-Length']))
```

I am sending requests through curl command

```
curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8881 --data-binary "@index.jpeg"
```

How do I get the incoming filename and type here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27183844/how-to-get-the-requested-file-name-in-basehttpserver-in-python

Comment: @R12568asdb not really, My question is how do I get the file name and type which I am sending

Comment: The thing is that the file is being sent as binary data. No metadata like this is intrinsically attached to the sent binary. So why don’t you just send a dictionary which includes the desired filepath when you transfer data between the client and the server?